# How to simulate obj-c blocks in Java as Lambdas?

Tags: java

The pattern below works a little bit like Obj-C's blocks. I'm wondering if it's possible to re-write this using java 8's Lambdas. And if did so, would executing the lambda span a new thread, or would it run within the same thread?

```
private interface RunnableBlock {
    public void runA(MyObj myObj);
    public void runB(MyObj myObj);
}

// frequently used method
private MyObj operateOnMyObj(short someParams, RunnableBlock runnableBlock) throws Exception {
    // do a lot of stuff... 

    // MyObj is generated here
    MyObj myObj = // blah blah..

    if(myCondition) {
        //common pre-runnable
        runnableBlock.runA(myObj);
        //common post-runnable
    } else {
        //other common pre-runnable
        runnableBlock.runB(myObj);
        //other common post-runnable
    }
    return myObj;
}

public void aMyObjConsumer() {
    // now to use the above
    MyObj myObj = operateOnMyObj(someParam,
        new RunnableBlock() {
            @Override public void runA(MyObj myObj) {
                // do stuff..
            }

            @Override public void runB(MyObj myObj) {
                // do different stuff.. 
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Objective-C, but I guess you want to run two different pieces of code depending on some condition, passed as a lambda expression? That would not work in Java.

Lambdas can only be used where a *Functional Interface* is required. Functional interfaces have exactly one abstract method. So you'd have to split your `runnableBlock` into two arguments. `Consumer` seems to be the appropriate interface from the standard library.

Anyways, it would not spawn a new thread. Lambdas are just syntactic replacements for anonymous implementations of functional interfaces. They are not inherently related to multithreading.

---

Example code (shortened):

```
// frequently used method
private MyObj operateOnMyObj(Consumer<MyObj> block1, Consumer<MyObj> block2 {
    // ...
    if (myCondition) {
        block1.accept(myObj);
    } else {
        block2.accept(myObj);
    }
    return myObj;
}

public void aMyObjConsumer() {
    // now to use the above
    MyObj myObj = operateOnMyObj((myObj) -> { /* do stuff */ }, (myObj) -> { /* do different stuff */ });
}
```

I assumed `menu` was a typo and should read `runnableBlock`, since `runB` is not used anywhere else.

Again, I don't know how it would work in Objective-C, but in Java it looks kind of awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What would that idea look in code?